# Can I marry my mother's elder sister's daughter's daughter?

Tags: nikah, legal

Assalamoalaikum,

Can I marry my mother's elder sister's daughter's daughter. Is it acceptable in Islam, please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salaamu alaikum.
Yes you can marry her, it is permissible in Islam according to this verse:

> [4:23] Prohibited for you (in marriage) are your mothers, your daughters, your sisters, the sisters of your fathers, the sisters of your mothers, the daughters of your brother, the daughters of your sister, your nursing mothers, the girls who nursed from the same woman as you, the mothers of your wives, the daughters of your wives with whom you .have consummated the marriage - if the marriage has not .been consummated, you may marry the daughter. Also prohibited for you are the women who were married to your genetic sons. Also, you shall not be married to two sisters at the same time - but do not break up existing marriages. GOD is Forgiver, Most Merciful."

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but what about the genetic disorders in offspring's,  Do we have such risk

Comment: @saif if there is something that runs in the family, then there is always going to be a risk yes, but it is nothing too much of an issue worry about.

Comment: @saif also consider performing istikarah before proposing to ensure that marrying this girl is the 100% right thing to do, as only Allah knows best. if you get a negative, dont feel sad and just remember that the right girl has already been written for you, its just a matter od time In Sha Allah

Comment: @saif may Allah SWT give you a happy and blessed marraige for both you and your wife and no evil harms any of you or your future children In Sha Allah. amen

Comment: plz include all ur comments related to the question in your answer.... one line answers are not very much constructive in here...

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser i dont mean to sound rude but i dont see the problem with a one lined answer if that one line entirely answers the question

Comment: There's noting wrong in it, true, but, people would sometimes like to hear on what basis is this one line answer justifiable, at least some explanation or a direct reference. Hope you'll understand.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser yes your right and my apologies. Ill put some evidence In Sha Allah

Comment: @TashannaChamma, well done, your answer can be considered as relatively a complete nice answer. Actually the above verse can be the best guidance for that.  / eligible of +1 vote / ___________ By the way, Can I give you a kindly recommendation about your photo? (Since it seems you are a (good) Muslim/ as you probably know, as much as I know, according to Islam, e.g. Noor:31, Ahzab33 make-up and Tabaroj (grooming, or perhaps attractiving the attention) for non-Mahram is haram. /

Comment: / So, your photo (profile) could be considered as  … to some extent. (And I assume it can be a little … from the view of many non-mahrams as well. / So, in that case, perhaps Allah considers it as sin if it attracts the attention of some or many non-mahrams. (I assume both Sunni and Shia agree with it (according to the order of Islam)) / Thus would you plz change that pic? (Although I know it is completely a personal matter for you as your option ... (just a suggestion) (as you wish) / Good luck dear TashannaChamma.

Comment: @السید____علی at first i didnt understand, and i got offended, but i read you other comments and i realised your right. That's actually my gmail photo, but i have changed it alhamdulillah, and jazaakullah kheir for your opinion :) by the way, you are right regarding the sunni/shiah views, though even if you had told me if you are shiah, it wouldn't have made a different, as you are still right

Comment: Alhamdollah you seem to be a logical Momen Muslim that accepted the matter (As the order of Islam) , although unfortunately many girls dont do it due to their passion, but you overcame Satan (well done) / Thus god willing you'll be able to overcome Satan in other fields as well. / Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, I always say if something was not forbidden by Allah then it is Halal. An existing answer here tells you exactly who you are not allowed to marry:

https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1308

Your Aunt's daughter (cousin) is something that is definitely OK to do, what you are asking for is second cousin which is also OK.

Islamically speaking, you should get a medical opinion on the marriage - which I advise anyone who wants to marry someone close to their family, to avoid having babies with disabilities. The advise from the Prophet PBUH is to marry someone from outside the family to decrease such issues.