# Can I marry the sister of my maternal uncle (who is not my own mother's brother)?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

I was interested to marry one girl. While after I got to know that she was my maternal uncle's sister. But he is not my own mother's brother.

Can I marry her or not?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question and concerns , JazakAllah

Comment: Oh, as @servant pointed out, you'd better elaborate your question. And would you please what does it mean "maternal uncle sister"? God bless you

Comment: Read the answer from this link and you will learn the rule of thumb: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/what-women-cant-a-man-marry

Answer (score 1):

Salaam.

It's difficult to answer given we don't know quite what you mean by 'maternal uncle sister'; we don't after all know which social-cultural tradition you're from.

In the tradition I know, Bengal - maternal uncle would mean

- an *actual* brother of your mother
- he is *actually* related to your mother as a brother, he might be a cousain say
- he is a close male friend of your mother; we then also say 'maternal uncle sister' for his daughter, which we regard as a sister.

Which one of these is it? It's obviously not the first; so it's between the last two; on what you say, it looks like you can marry her - but it's good to be clear.

Comment: maternal uncle is same in everywhere. the question is crystal clear, no way of confusion as he clearly told "he is not my own mother's brother".

Answer (score -1):

You can marry her, there is no restriction from Islamic view.

Don't forget to make Istikhara before marriage, so that you could get help from the Almighty.

May Allah accept your conjugal life.

Jajakallah.

Comment: istikhara is for only when things on paper are not obvious. If things on paper are obviously good or bad...or that through consultation you can handle things, then make your decision that way

Comment: Can you please explain your answer, **as an edit** to your original answer?

Comment: What do you expect by "explain"? @Pureferret

Comment: Which parts of the Quran or hadith apply to this specific situation. Why do they apply?  That will give confidence to the reader of this answer that this is an accurate answer.

Answer (score -1):

All praises and thanks are due to Allah. And regarding the answer of your question , marrying is one of the legal ways of our Prophet Muhammad (p.b.u.h) Therefore, you can marry this girl and there is nothing wrong with that. And the Almighty Allah knows best.

و جزاك اللّٰه خير الجزاء والسلام عليكم ورحمة اللّٰه وبركاته

Comment: nothing can? even if Allah Subhanahu wa ta'ala wishes though?

Comment: Can you please explain your answer, **as an edit** to your original answer?