# Is a marriage with the daughter of fathers brother or the daughter of the mothers sister permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

Can I marry my Fathers brothers daughter, she is also my Mothers sisters daughter.
My parents brother and sister are married to each other.

Answer (score 3):

In the Quran you may read:

> O Prophet, indeed We have made lawful to you your wives to whom you have given their due compensation and those your right hand possesses from what Allah has returned to you [of captives] and the **daughters of your paternal uncles** and the daughters of your paternal aunts and the daughters of your maternal uncles and the **daughters of your maternal aunts** who emigrated with you and a believing woman if she gives herself to the Prophet [and] if the Prophet wishes to marry her, [this is] only for you, excluding the [other] believers. ... ([33:50](http://legacy.quran.com/33/50))

So basically from a halal-haram or shari'a point of view such a marriage is halal, but one should or is strongly invited to do medical check for    hereditary disease etc. before marrying to stay on the safe site based on [this fatwa (in Arabic](http://www.awqaf.gov.ae/Fatwa.aspx?SectionID=9&RefID=7936) from the General authority of Islamic affairs and endowments of the U.A.E.. However this fatwa [islamqa#139517](https://islamqa.info/ar/139517) denies that marrying a close relative per se is a reason for hereditary diseases of the offspring.

Also check [Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry)