# can i a man marry from the sister of her alive wife?

Tags: quran, hadith, wife

Kindly explain with logical reasons. Reasons must be from quran majid and ahadis. As i am already confused that why we cant marry. There is no logical reasoning if we say it directly.

Comment: Your question is unclear. A man can not be married to two sisters simultaneously.  [Quran 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23):  { *Prohibited to you ... that you take [in marriage] two sisters simultaneously* }; also see [Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/).

Comment: I don't have any logical reasons for not praying only four times a day. But I pray five times instead because Allah wills it. Likewise you can't look for logical reasons for specific commands.

Comment: @Uma Gave you the answer from the Quran. As for logical reasons, The Z gave a good point. I'll add to that, if you have children from both wives, who are sisters, are your children (from different wives) step-brothers and step-sisters, or are they cousins??? This situation creates a lot of confusion and may lead to undesired consequences.