# Marriage of adopted humans

Tags: nikah, fiqh, family, child-adoption

Is the marriage of a child of blood with his adopted sister and / or the marriage between a daughter of blood and his adopted brother lawful? And in the case of a man adopted from a family and a woman adopted from another family by the same parents, would the marriage between these two siblings be lawful?

Comment: In fact an adopted child or relative is a foreigner for which the rules of non-Mahrams apply.

Answer (score 3):

Adoption, by itself, does not create any real relationships and hence does not establish any marriage prohibitions.

> وما جعل أدعياءكم أبناءكم ذلكم قولكم بأفواهكم والله يقول الحق وهو يهدي السبيل
>
> And he has not made your adopted sons your [true] sons. That is [merely] your saying by your mouths, but Allah says the truth, and He guides to the [right] way.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 33:4](http://quran.com/33/4)</sup>

However if an adopted child was breastfed by the woman who adopted him\her, that would create prohibitions. Please refer to "[Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry)".