# Is nikkah allow with the adoptive daughter of the woman a man had muttah?

Tags: nikah, nikah-al-mutah, child-adoption

Can a person male who had muttah with a woman after ending muttah marry make permenant nikkah with her adoptive daughter (not real daughter)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry)

Comment: Also see [Marriage of adopted humans](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52233/marriage-of-adopted-humans)