# About marrying someone’s daughter whom I call as sister

Tags: nikah

Assalamualaikum,
The question I have is about a marriage proposal, where the girl is my relative abd I call her “sister”. In which way she is my sister is “she is my mom’s father’s younger brother’s daughter’s daughter” I hope you understand the family tree.

So coming to the point can I marry her. I need some clear answers, so that I can make my decisions further.
Assalamualaikumasalam.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Marriage of adopted humans](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52233/marriage-of-adopted-humans)

Answer (score 1):

This falls under the category of "**Adoption**".

[Adopted sisters are not real sisters.](https://www.islamicboard.com/family-amp-society/134307480-adoption-islam.html)

According to the Islamic law of [prohibited marriages based on consanguinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_in_Islam#Prohibitions_based_on_consanguinity) and [prohibited marriage partners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_in_Islam#Prohibited_marriage_partners), this relationship falls into the category of Halal or permitted.

In Islamic Shariah law, the term "sister" can refer to one of two relationships:

1. **Mahram (Non-Marriageable Kin)**: This includes your biological sisters, with whom marriage is strictly forbidden. The Quran explicitly mentions that marriage is not permitted with one's sisters in Surah An-Nisa (4:23).
2. **Non-Mahram (Marriageable Kin)**: If you refer to a woman as "sister" but she is not actually your biological or foster sister (i.e., she is not related to you by blood, breastfeeding, or adoption according to Islamic law), then she is not considered a mahram to you. In this case, it is generally permissible to marry her if all other conditions for a lawful marriage in Islam are met.