# Is mutah allowed with woman and her daughter both

Tags: halal-haram, nikah-al-mutah

If i do mutah with a woman who is a divorcee, for 1 hour and after expiration of  1 hour can i do mutah with the same woman's daughter who is Baaligh if the woman agrees to it.

Answer (score 3):

Basically the answer of [Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry) should answer this question clearly as even if this marriage is temporary the relevant rules of nikah apply. As Allah the almighty say:

> Prohibited to you [for marriage] are …  **your wives' mothers**, and **your step-daughters** under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in. … ([4:23](https://legacy.quran.com/4/23))

But if you want a shi'a reference on the website of the marji' an-Najafi (See [here](http://www.alnajafy.com/list/mainnews-66-1-677-128-1.html) in Arabic) you may find:
 <sub>In the following I'll translate from Arabic language (with some additional explanation in parenthesis). As this is a translation of my own take it with the necessary care.</sub>

> **السؤال:** هل يجوز الجمع بين الام وبنتها والأخوات في زواج المتعة وان كان لا يجوز متى يمكن التمتع بأخت المتمتع بها سابقاً هل بعد انتهاء المدة ام بعد الحيضتين ؟
>   **The question:** Is it allowed to marry both mother and her daughter or sisters in nikah al-Mut'ah. And if it is not permissible when is it possible to have pleaser (perform mut'ah) with the sister of a woman one had nikah al-Muta'ah with before, is it after then end of the (set) time (for the nikah al-Mu'ath) or after two menses?
>
> **الجواب:** بسمه سبحانه : لا يجوز الجمع بين الام وبنتها فاذا عقد على احداهما حرمت عليه الاخرى مؤبداً وكذا لا يجوز الجمع بين الاختين الا بعد انتهاء مدة العدة للمتمتع بها وينبغي ان يعلم انه ان عقد على الام ولم يدخل بها وفارقها جاز له الزواج على ابنتها , وان عقد على البنت فلا يجوز الزواج بأمها سواء دخل بالبنت ام لم يدخل , والله العالم .
>   **The answer:** In His name glorified be He: It is not permissible to marry a mother and her daughter both so if one has married one of them the other is haraam for ever. And also it is not permissible to marry two sisters only after the 'iddah of a woman that has been married in nikah al-Mut'ah has ended, and one also should know that if one has married the mother, but didn't consume the marriage and separated from her it is allowed to marry her daughter. But if one has married the daughter then marrying her mother is not permissible no matter if one consumed the the marriage of not. And Allah is the legist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's allowed.

- If you ever did a nikah with a woman then you'll always be mahram to her children.
- If you ever did a nikah with a women then you'll always be mahram to her parents.

Just some side notes:

- mutah with a virgin is frowned upon. It's unfair to her as she's to be married. If she has never been married before then you need permission of her guardian.
- I already said this isn't allowed, but generally the age difference between the man and woman should be reasonable. In the question asked, either the man is too young for a woman or too old for another which isn't a good thing.