# I and my elder sister are from same mother but different fathers....can I marry her son?

Tags: nikah

I and my elder sister are from same mother but different fathers .can I marry her son?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry) In general, rulings for a half sister are the same as that for a proper sister as both come under the meaning of the word "sister".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot marry her. You share the same mother as your sister which makes you blood related hence you cannot marry her or her daughters.
“Forbidden unto you are your mothers, and your daughters, and your sisters, and your father’s sisters, and your mother’s sisters, and your brother’s daughters and your sister’s daughters, and your foster-mothers, and your foster-sisters, and your mothers-in-law, and your step-daughters who are under your protection (born) of your women unto whom ye have gone in – but if ye have not gone in unto them, then it is no sin for you (to marry their daughters) – and the wives of your sons who (spring) from your own loins. And (it is forbidden unto you) that ye should have two sisters together, except what hath already happened (of that nature) in the past. Lo! Allah is ever Forgiving, Merciful. [4:23]”

This verse is the basis for the rulings on who are one’s mahram. Unmarriageable kin can be divided into three categories: (1) those related by blood [s: half siblings would fall here], (2) those related by marriage, (3) and those related by breastfeeding. [al-Imam al-Kasani, Bada’i`al-Sana’i`]