# When can a virgin muslim man marry a raped woman, and when isn't that possible?

Tags: nikah, men-women, rape

Salam everyone,

Are there some conditions to marry a raped woman who aborted twice ?
She was still a child, and both were in the first month pregnancy.

Also are there some stories in the Quran, or Sunnah about raped woman ?

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's even commendable to marry them.
Here is what I found :
"..They can marry afterwards just fine. The Prophet (saw), for example, married almost exclusively divorced or widowed women, who were also looked down upon. With some Qiyas (analogy), we can then see that marrying those women who have been raped would not be something looked down upon, but that should be honoured or upheld..."

"... there are no conditions that I know of that would apply in the case of the woman you had described, except that she would have to observe iddah, according to one opinion (but not according to the Malikis)..."

"...There are hadiths pertaining to the marriage of devirginized women who have previously committed adultry and that marrying them for their sutra yields a great reward..."

Answer (score 1):

The women who are forbidden to be married are covered here: [Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry). As long as the woman is not among those it is permitted to marry her, because she is included in the general meaning of:

> وأحل لكم ما وراء ذلكم
>
> And lawful to you are [all others] beyond these
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:24](http://quran.com/4/24)</sup>

> وأنكحوا الأيامى منكم
>
> And marry the unmarried among you
>
> <sup>— [Quran 24:32](http://quran.com/24/32)</sup>