# According to Quran 4:23, are step-daughters not under the husband’s guardianship mahrams?

Tags: quran, fiqh, tafseer, mahram

This part of Quran 4:23 says

> “your step daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in”

Does this only apply to step daughters under the second husband’s guardianship or all step daughters?

Comment: Somewhat relevant [Who are the women a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry)

Answer (score 3):

According to the vast majority, the prohibition applies to all step-daughters from a woman with whom marriage has been consummated. اللاتي في حجوركم (under your guardianship) is an expression of the prevalent case and is not a condition.

It is also evident from the fact that the verse goes on to say:

> ربائبكم اللاتي في حجوركم من نسائكم اللاتي دخلتم بهن **فإن لم تكونوا دخلتم بهن فلا جناح عليكم**
>
> your step-daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in. **But if you have not gone in unto them, there is no sin upon you.**
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23?translations=20)</sup>

This part only says that 'there is no sin upon you if the marriage has not been consummated', and does not say that 'there is no sin upon you if the step-daughter is not raised under your guardianship'. It proves that being raised under the step-father's guardianship is not a condition.

---

> واتفق الفقهاء على أن الربيبة تحرم على زوج أمها إذا دخل بالأم ، وإن لم تكن الربيبة في حجره . وشذ بعض المتقدمين وأهل الظاهر فقالوا : لا تحرم عليه الربيبة إلا أن تكون في حجر المتزوج بأمها ؛ فلو كانت في بلد آخر وفارق الأم بعد الدخول فله أن يتزوج بها
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura4-aya23.html#qortobi)</sup>

> وأما قوله : ( وربائبكم اللاتي في حجوركم ) فجمهور الأئمة على أن الربيبة حرام سواء كانت في حجر الرجل أو لم تكن في حجره ، قالوا : وهذا الخطاب خرج مخرج الغالب
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura4-aya23.html#katheer)</sup>