# Can I marry my brother's wife after his death?

Tags: fiqh, nikah

My younger brother has died. Can I marry his wife?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry)

Comment: A widow or divorcee of a brother is not listed among the mahrams. Meaning yes you can marry her, as long as there is no other problem which is omitted in the question.