# Can I Marry the Daughter of My Mother's Sister's Son Who Married Another Sister's Daughter?

Tags: nikah

My mother's sister's son married another sister's daughter. Is it permissible for me to marry their daughter now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry)