# Did the prophet Mohammad follow all of the Sharia?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

In [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2614/2469), GoldPseudo says

> Admittedly, just because the prophet was granted certain privileges does not mean they are applicable to Muslims on the whole

Does this mean that the Prophet Mohammad did not follow all of the laws of Islam?  What does this mean that the prophet might have been granted privileges that other Muslims do not have?

Comment: I recommend you to change your title at least...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did the Prophet (SAW) himself fully adhere to the rules imposed on all Muslims?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/did-the-prophet-saw-himself-fully-adhere-to-the-rules-imposed-on-all-muslims)

Answer (score 7):

Yes of course the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon) followed the Shariah, as well as he was given certain privileges no other got.  The context in which GoldPseudo said that, was that of marriage, and that was that he was allowed more then four wives, where we can only marry four at one time, indicating that we can most likely handle four at a time and no more, and still do justice, and be fair to all of them.  There are some reasons, and wisdom behind the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) being allowed more then four.  I shall mention only one to get the point across.

Among the wisdom is that Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) is the best role model for us, and he had the best and highest of character, and we try to be like him even in the smallest things, in the sense of his good character and so on.  Because he was allowed more then four, we have with us different aspects of his house life, and how he treated his family, and how he used to take care of them and so on.  Also we have certain aspects or knowledge of this religion narrated by different wives of his, at different times, and so on.  So this is among the wisdom of he being allowed more then four.  Also I forgot to mention, and has been said by (Ansari), is that yes some things maybe lax for him, but far more were stricter, and he was held at a high standard, where things have been made lax for us, so to not put hardship on us.  I will end with this, I ask Allah guide us all.

Comment: You may want to note that while some things were more "relaxed" for him, far more were stricter, such as the night prayer, sunan rawatib, prohibition of receiving charity, and a number of other things.

Comment: @AlUmmatمجاهد Is there a proof that the Sunnah prohibits taking more than 4 wives. The Quran is not explicit enough to put a definite limitation on the number of wives like 2,3,4,...

Comment: @Ali http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/8206/9