# Is the second marriage valid if only the second wife's family knows about it?

Tags: nikah, relationships, family

I have been married for a year now. I have met a woman recently who is much older than me and have a good deen. But she is financially unstable. Iam willing to marry her and support her financially. But if my family and my first wife get to know about this they will reject. Is the marriage valid if only the second wife's family knows about it

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Please check some existing questions like [Where is the proof that a man can marry a second wife without the first knowing?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46345/where-is-the-proof-that-a-man-can-marry-a-second-wife-without-the-first-knowing?rq=1) as there are certainly some duplicate posts on the site.

Comment: Also see [Can a wife deny her husband to marry more women?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70199/) and [Marrying a second woman behind your wife's back: is it wrong and can Quran/Hadith prove this?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56186/) etc.